# Create Excel chart showing % change (multiple industries) over time

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'd like to create a chart that shows changes in percentage for several industries over a number of years, similar to this example:

[image]

I've attempted to arrange my data to make it easier to chart, but I'm not having any luck getting the charts correct. See the following screencaps:

[image]

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem. You're in luck. The solution is easy.

Whenever Excel encounters numbers, it will try to chart these as values in a chart.

You can trick Excel into recognising the years as categories instead of a series with a simple move:

Delete the label in the table that says "Year". Then select from the empty (previously "Year") cell to the end of the data table. Do NOT include the sector column in your selection. Your selection should look like this:

[image]

Then insert a line chart while these cells are selected. The result will look similar to this:

[image]

You don't need the "sector" column in the chart at all. Beat the chart title into shape as you need it.

If you use a Line Chart, and you want the years ascending from left to right, format the axis and specify a date/time axis instead of a text axis. That will put the years in chronological order.

[image]

**The special tip #1:**

With no header label for column B, Excel will **NOT** even try to chart these values as series, but will instead place these values as categories on the X axis. Which is what you want.

**The special tip #2:**

Once you have created the chart, you can boldly put a text label back into cell B2. You may want to do that for your own understanding of what the data is about.

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Teylyn's answer is good and that approach works for your data.  However, I would approach it a little different as a matter of personal preference.

I would treat the years as a continuous variable rather than categories.  For your data, you get the same result, but if you happened to be missing a year of data, treating it as a continuous variable would keep the graph proportional to time.  If the years are treated as categories, the years are just labels and each row's data is just stacked one after the other.

With this approach, you can use your data without modification, including the year label.  Just highlight the four data columns, including the labels (but ignore that first, non-data column).  Select scatter chart, and you get a chart that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]